# JSF <p:fieldset> align side by side rendered in different heights based on the components inside them which are generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I am trying to achieve this [Visit](http://jsfiddle.net/q9v9j/13/)  but both the fieldset should have equal heights unlike given in the example
 I am trying give equal heights for the two field set having   dynamically generated contents and I am trying to do it in the JSF primefaces-3.4.1.

```
 <pfieldset id="id1" style="align:left;width:auto;height:100%;margin-right:1em;margin-left:1em;display:inline-block">
 <p:fieldset id="id2" style="width:auto;height:100%;margin-left:1m;display:inline-block">
```

On page load the two fieldsets are having equal heights 
There is an "edit" button to click and modify the contents inside the fieldset.
When I click the edit button  the fieldset size may decrease and increase based upon the contents inside them but either way both the fieldset should have equal heights.

But the fielset are not equal in heights when I click the edit button.One fieldset height  is larger than the other.

Really appreciate if any suggestions were given to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have two fieldset declared  side by side  inside a panelgrid

<p:fieldset id="id1" style="align:left;width:auto;height:100%;margin-right:1em;margin-left:1em;display:inline-block">
<p:fieldset id="id2" style="width:auto;height:100%;margin-left:1m;display:inline-block">

Comment: Please edit your question to add the extra information.